# quisiera comprender de mejor manera el funcionamiento de esta funcion asincrona

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

sucede que estoy leyendo el codigo de un poryecto sobre una aplicacion en react con redux referente a perros y informacion de ellos, solo que al leer este codgo ubicado en la carpeta de action de redux no entiendo muy bien el comportamiento del dispatch, si alguien me lo pudiera aclara le quedaria muy agradeciddo.

```
export function getBreed(payload) {//dogs by name
    return async function (dispatch) {
        try {
            var json = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/dogs?name=" + payload)
            return dispatch ({
                type: GET_BREED,
                payload: json.data
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso es posibe solamente gracias a  que se esta usando el middleware Thunk. Nativamente redux no permite ningun tipo de accion asincrona ni en el store, ni el reducer, ni en las actions.  El thunk permite despachar una asincronia que con su resposne ejecuta a su vez una dispatch normal